# XML DTD Errors no declaration for element spend

Tags: xml, dtd

it's my first day using XML we just had a lecture on it, but I have to do a lab. I'm having a few errors when validating my code. I am still quite confused. I found that I wanted headers, ministry, minister, year and spend and this required me to use the code following, even though our lecturer used  etc, but when I did it my headers were just name, name2, name3 which seemed annoying. So i have to use  to get the header to say ministry. I  then added my DTD and a now having parse issues, it keeps saying no declaration for element spend. Please help :) Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE spending 
[
<!ELEMENT spending (minister+)>
<!ELEMENT minister (year+)>
<!ELEMENT year (spend?)>
<!ATTLIST ministry
    ministry    CDATA   #REQUIRED
>
<!ATTLIST minister
        minister    CDATA   #IMPLIED
>
<!ATTLIST    year
    year    CDATA   #REQUIRED
>
<!ATTLIST   spend
    spend   ID  #REQUIRED
>
]>
<spending>
    <ministry ministry="Education">
        <minister minister="Phil Amos">
            <year year="1972">
                <spend>335</spend>
            </year>
            <year year="1973">
                <spend>377</spend>
            </year>
            <year year="1974">
                <spend>440</spend>
            </year>
            <year year="1975">
                <spend>527</spend>
            </year>
        </minister>
        <minister minister="Les Gandar">
            <year year="1976">
                <spend>627</spend>
            </year>
            <year year="1977">
                <spend>699</spend>
            </year>
            <year year="1976">
                <spend>808</spend>
            </year>
        </minister>
    </ministry>
</spending>
```

Comment: _“it keeps saying no declaration for element spend”_ – well of course it does, because you didn’t declare it. You declared all other elements – so what makes you think `spend` would not need the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `spend` element, with something like that:

```
<!ELEMENT spend (#PCDATA) >
```

In your dtd, you have -- for the moment -- only declared the **attributes** for this element. And you will have the problem for `year`, `ministry`, ...